# CSS selector in the URL

Tags: html, css, url, css-selectors

When you have a url like this `www.example.com/#signup`, what the browser does is just to focus it's view on the HTML element with id `signup`, is that right?

Is it possible to change the element's CSS style if it's focused in that way?

*E.g.* let's say I have a div element, with the id `signup`, then if I enter `www.example.com`, the div's background is white and if I enter `www.example.com/#signup` it's yellow. Like "emphasizing" the sign up form. Is this at all possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
:target { background-color: yellow; }
```

The `:target` psuedo-class does exactly this.

Comment: I'm not sure. Probably not, to be honest, but that can be remedied by JS: `var a = document.getElementById(location.hash.substr(1)); if( a) a.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';`

Comment: @John Doe: Not IE8 and older.

Answer (score 1):

You can read the `window.location.hash` property when the page loads and apply the corresponding css classs. Something like:

```
<script type='text/javascript>
function init(){ 
    var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
    var element = document.getElementById(hash);
    if(element){
        element.className += " emphasize";
    }
}
</script>

<body onload="init()">
...
</body>
```